# Add multiple values including a range to a rails select dropdown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a dropdown in my rails app where I want users to be able to select from a range of numbers as well as the value "Still Attending".

Could someone help me work this out. I have the range working fine but when I add

```
, "Still Attending"
```

It stops working.

```
<%= select(:year, '', options_for_select(2021.downto(1950), "Still Attending"), { prompt: "Select Year" }, class: "input border border-grey-light text-sm mt-2 w-full") %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want "Still Attending" to be the first choice, you can make it the first element in the options array.

```
<%= select(:year, '', options_for_select(["Still Attending"] + 2021.downto(1950).to_a), { prompt: "Select Year" }, class: "input border border-grey-light text-sm mt-2 w-full") %>
```

The second argument in options_for_select is just to set the current "selected" option, it's not a new option in its own right.